# How to add a custom Identity Provider (OIDC) mapper

Tags: keycloak

I wrote my own custom token mapper to map all roles assigned per group to a user, to the access token as a single claim that is a mapping (object) from group name to roles-list.

However I can't seem to get it deployed. This is my custom mapper:

```
public class HierarchicalAttributesMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper 
    implements OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCIDTokenMapper, UserInfoTokenMapper {...}
```

It is based on the GroupMembershipMapper. I added the following file in the top-level of the compiled jar:

```
META-INF/services/org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityProviderMapper
```

With the FQN of my HierarchicalAttributesMapper. When running my docker container for keycloak, mounting to the /opt/jboss/standalone/deployments folder it gets recognized, but then throws this warning:

```
[org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Failed to define class 
technology.idlab.cot.keycloak.oidc.HierarchicalAttributesMapper in Module 
"deployment.keycloak-oidc-hierarchical-attributes-mapper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link 
technology/idlab/cot/keycloak/oidc/HierarchicalAttributesMapper (Module 
"deployment.keycloak-oidc-hierarchical-attributes-mapper-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" 
from Service Module Loader): 
    org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/OIDCAccessTokenMapper

(stack-trace omitted)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Yes, the missing link was the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file that describes the needed dependencies from keycloak. [link](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#using-the-keycloak-deployer)

Comment: what did you add to `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`?
I added `<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>` and more - but it still does not work...

Comment: This question is really old, but I managed to dig up the file contents and thus modules I had back then. I don't have any clue anymore what it all meant however:
`<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>`, `<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>`, `<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>`, `<module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>`.